# Web 8 Checked-Out Items Only for Logged in User?

Tags: web8, cme, user-management

I noticed that in Web 8, we no longer have the capability to see all of the checked out items.

The shortcut only shows things that are checked out to the logged-in user.

Does anyone know if there is a setting somewhere that we need to change or if that is just a feature of Web 8?

Comment: are you a system admin? I am on SDL Web 8.5 and I see all items checked out by all users.

Comment: As sys admin in 2013 I am able to see all users checked-out.. but in Web 8.1.1 as sys admin, I am only able to see my checked-out items

Comment: did you ask customer support? perhas there's an issue in 8.1.1? It works just fine for us in 8.5

Comment: Okay. I will submit a ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no intended change in functionality. A hotfix is available to correct this issue (CME_8.1.1.2302) so contact Customer Support to get the fix.

Comment: I forget, is this only admin capabilities - to see everyone's checked-out items? Is it for non-admins in any release => 8.1.1?

Comment: It's still reserved for admins only. You are essentially throwing away someone else's data, so it should be something only a few people can do. But perhaps it could be a little more flexible than just Tridion admins. Post on ideas.sdl.com perhaps?

Comment: Will do @PeterKjaer